# data dont load in the Searchable dropdown Select Box using Ajax in laravel 8

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I want to show my products list in the drop down Select Box but don't show their any data .I think i made a mistake but i cant find it. Please help to fix the problem.

My **Product.blade.php** File:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

   <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{URL::to('/stockupdate')}}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#category_item').selectpicker();

   load_data('category_data');

  function load_data(type, ids = '')
  {
    $.ajax({
      headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
      url:"{{ url('/productlist') }}",
      method:"POST",
      data:{type:type, ids:ids},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        var html = '';
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
        {
          html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].Product_name+'</option>';
        }
        if(type == 'category_data')
        {
          $('#category_item').html(html);
          $('#category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
       
      }
    })
  }

});
</script>
```

**My Controller.com**

```
public function productlist() 
     {
       $data= DB::table('Products')  
       ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
       ->get();  
      return view ('layouts.productstocklist',compact('data'));  

     }
```

**My Route**

```
Route::get('/productlist',[AppController::class, 'productlist']);
```

Comment: you send POST `method: "POST"` while your route is defined as a GET.
`Route::get` should be `Route::post`

Comment: Yes, i correction this Route::post('/productlist',[AppController::class, 'productlist'])->name('productlist');. but dont load the data.

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't load the data? do you see the request in the network of the browser (Developer tools)? I think you mean that the data is not rendered into the page. Also. I see that in the controller you return the view(in that case HTML) while in JS you expect `dataType:"json",`

Comment: @Oleksandr H.
yes data don't rendering. How to through data from controller ?

Comment: `return response()->json(compact('data'));`

Comment: check out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#json-responses